# Specification for Solana RPC API

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api, api

Is Solana's [JSON RPC API doc](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api) generated off a spec, like [OpenRPC](https://open-rpc.org/)? Or is it just manually updated by core devs?

Browsing the [commits](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/commits/master/docs/src/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api.md), it feels like it is the latter.

Comment: It's the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presently, the specification is updated manually.

Comment: However, I am kickstarting an effort to generate both the Rust interface implementation _and_ the Typescript interface from a single specification. My hope is that it will cut down on inconsistencies between the two, _and_ let us eliminate all of the client-side validation of server responses that we do in `@solana/web3.js` today.

Comment: Read more about that effort, here: https://twitter.com/steveluscher/status/1601245146276073474